# What would be a better method for collisions in my game?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, game-physics

When the character collides with the obstacles the game is over. It technically works but the problem that I need to fix is that the character is able to overlap with the obstacles and even get away without a game over. The two need to really overlap in order to cause a game over.

Now I think the problem may be because they collide when at the same position. If they have to have the same position does that mean it is when their `center point / pixel` meet because what exactly is the position? Is it the center of the image or the edge `pixels` of the image.

I'm really struggling with this and would like some help. Thank you!

```
//CHARACTER COLLISION

-(void)checkGameOver{
if(GAMESTART){
    if(flyCopter.position.x >= CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - flyCopter.copterWidth/2 - 6){
      [self showOver];
    }

    if(flyCopter.position.x <= CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + flyCopter.copterWidth/2 + 6){
      [self showOver];
    }

    [self compareCP:blockTmp1 :flyCopter];
    [self compareCP:blockTmp2 :flyCopter];
    if(flyCopter.position.y <= blockTmp1.position.y - 0 + blockTmp1.size.height + 0)
    if(flyCopter.position.x <= blockTmp1.position.x +20 + blockTmp1.size.width + 0)
    //if(flyCopter.position.y <= blockTmp2.position.y + blockTmp2.size.height)
    //if(flyCopter.position.x <= blockTmp2.position.x + blockTmp2.size.width)
    //if(flyCopter.position.y <= blockTmp3.position.y + blockTmp3.size.height)
    //if(flyCopter.position.x <= blockTmp3.position.x + blockTmp3.size.width)
    //if(flyCopter.position.y <= blockTmp4.position.y + blockTmp4.size.height)
    //if(flyCopter.position.x >= blockTmp4.position.x + blockTmp4.size.width)
    {
        [self compareCP:blockTmp3 :flyCopter];
        [self compareCP:blockTmp4 :flyCopter];
    }

    [self compareCP:blockTmp5 :flyCopter];
    [self compareCP:blockTmp6 :flyCopter];
    if(flyCopter.position.y <= blockTmp5.position.y - 0 + blockTmp5.size.height + 0)
    if(flyCopter.position.x <= blockTmp5.position.x +20 + blockTmp5.size.width + 0)

    {
        [self compareCP:blockTmp7 :flyCopter];
        [self compareCP:blockTmp8 :flyCopter];
    }

    [self compareCP:blockTmp9 :flyCopter];
    [self compareCP:blockTmp10 :flyCopter];
    if(flyCopter.position.y <= blockTmp9.position.y - 0 + blockTmp9.size.height + 0)
      if(flyCopter.position.x <= blockTmp9.position.x +20 + blockTmp9.size.width + 0)

    {
        [self compareCP:blockTmp11 :flyCopter];
        [self compareCP:blockTmp12 :flyCopter];
    }
  }
}


-(void)compareCP:(SKSpriteNode*)flyCopters : (SKSpriteNode*)blocks{
if(flyCopters){
        if ([blocks intersectsNode:flyCopters]) {
            [self showOver];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can check box2d. it is very common physics lib

Answer (score -1):

If your using Sprite Kit then take advantage of SKPhysicsBody and SKPhysicsWorld.

For a start read over Apple's: [Sprite Kit Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW3).

Also check out this tutorial for collisions: [Space Invaders - Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/51068/how-to-make-a-game-like-space-invaders-with-sprite-kit-tutorial-part-1)